# implement a distributed deployment approach in messagebroker

Tags: messagebroker

I am making a broker that I want to deploy on three servers and I want to run it on only one one by one.flow that is running called active flow and others are passive.when it runs it send an email that flow is running on server x.

can we do this broker through a flag. 
i.e. to implement a distributed deployment approach

Answer (score 0):

The best approach would be to use a multi instance broker so that you only have one node active at any one time, you could then have either in the onInitialize() method of a JCN, or in a timeout control driven flow a branch of subflow which creates an email based on the local hostname.